# A sum involving Bernoulli numbers and product of binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients, bernoulli-numbers

I came across a sum involving Bernoulli numbers and product of binomial coefficients during a computation. Precisely, it is $\sum\limits_{c=0}^m B_c\binom{r}{c}\binom{r-c}{m-c}$ where $B_c$ denotes the $c$th Bernoulli number, $r\geq m$, $m\geq 3$, and $m$ odd. Numerically I could evaluate it to be 0 through the sage code  given [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwrUrBVMDbk5UrLL1LIVcjMU4g21jHV0dPTKYq14uVSAIKCosy8Eo3i0lyN6KTUorz80pycTI1kTa2kzLz83MzEHI0iHRSebrJOrm6ypgLIxGSwiQYg83JjYzU1AePMILc=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==). Is there anyway to see it in general that this sum is indeed 0 for any general $r$ and $m$ with these properties? I can also see that the binomial product is symmetric from the both the ends of the sum. That is, $\binom{r}{j}\binom{r-j}{m-j}$ and $\binom{r}{m-j}\binom{r-m+j}{j}$ are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\binom{r}{c}\binom{r-c}{m-c}=\frac{r!(r-c)!}{c!(r-c)!(m-c)!(r-m)!}=\frac{r!}{m!(r-m)!}\frac{m!}{c!(m-c)!}=\binom{r}{m}\binom{m}{c}$, then $\sum\limits_{c=0}^m B_c\binom{r}{c}\binom{r-c}{m-c}=\binom{r}{m} \sum\limits_{c=0}^m \binom{m}{c}B_c=0$.

Comment: Thank you @rRené Gy ! I missed the simple but important link.

Answer (score 0):

With Mathematica I have only a solution to series:

$$\sum _{c=0}^m B_c \binom{r}{c} \binom{r-c}{m-c}=-\frac{\zeta (1-m) (-1+m-r)!}{(-1+m)! (-1-r)!}$$ for: $m>1$

Comment: @Vishnu Namboothiri K with **Mathematica** and **Maple**: `FullSimplify[-((Zeta[1 - m] (-1 + m - r)!)/((-1 + m)! (-1 - r)!)) /. 
   m -> 2 m - 1 /. r -> m, 
 Assumptions -> {m \[Element] PositiveIntegers, m > 1}]` give me `0`.

Comment: I would write $$
\frac{{( - 1 + m - r)!}}{{( - 1 - r)!}} = ( - 1)^m \frac{{r!}}{{(r - m)!}}
$$ given that $r \ge m$. With $(m-1)!=m!/m$ you could write the final result in terms of $\binom{r}{m}$.